# Log back into terminal to see how rsync is doing

Tags: bash, rsync

I have a bash script which copies one drive to another which is working fine.
I am using the `-v` option so it outputs on the terminal as it performs the operation.

Is it possible to log out of the terminal and then log back in again to see how far it has got?

Comment: That's what a terminal multiplexer supposed to do, like `tmux` and  `GNU screen` and friends...

Comment: If you save the output and errput then you can see what happened when reconnecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes Ian,

There's this beautiful program called "screen" which gives you such use case.

List of useful Steps:

1. Spawn a new screen session by typing `screen`
2. Enter your rsync command here with -v parameter
3. Detach your current screen session using `ctrl + a + d`
4. This will bring you to a main terminal session
5. Query all live sessions using `screen -ls`
6. Once you confirm the screen id you want to login/re-attach to, use the command `screen -r "id"` to regain the access

Some more resources for reference:
https://www.tecmint.com/screen-command-examples-to-manage-linux-terminals/

tmux is another program that gives you similar functionality.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: `screen` is not really necessary if you learn to run noninteractive jobs in the background. Redirect output to a file; examine that file from any convenient terminal when you need to see the progress.

Comment: True. pushing tasks to the background and redirecting op/error to a file. the author wanted to log back to the previous state. That's why suggested the screen.